# Adjective after noun and clause as pronoun and object

Tags: grammar

I would like to know more about the grammatical structure of the following sentence.

> The context necessary to give examples would be much longer than what he claimed.

Is it correct to use adjective immediate after the noun "context", I wonder if this sentence is correct in grammar. Why not " the context [that is ] necessary....?Is it common to omit "that is"? and does the clause "what he claimed " acts as a pronoun and a object in the whole sentence. thx

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? The phrase _necessary to give examples_ identifies the context being referred to. _What_ could well be omitted.

Comment: I read that in a patreon blog post. I wonder if this sentence is correct in grammar. Why not " the context [that is ] necessary....?Is it common to omit "that is"?

Comment: Very common, in expressions like _the ingredients necessary for making the cake - the reasons given for doing this_ etc.

Comment: There is no 'omission' of "that is". They are just two different kinds of modifier of "context", i.e. an adjective phrase and a relative clause. "hat he claimed" is a noun phrase in a fused relative construction, where "what" means "that which".